# How to refer to a company a person works for? [job application]

Tags: preposition

If I apply to a job advertisement from a company where I'm told to write to "*Frau xyz*" (secretary) is it okay to say "*Sehr geehrte Frau xyz, ich bin auf **Ihre** Firma durch das Stellenangebot aufmerksam geworden*"? I know the sentence is not quite perfect (word order and so on) but I want to know how to refer to the company (with a preposition) in a correct way.

Comment: Du solltest dazuschreiben, was Dich zweifeln lässt.

Comment: Wenn Du schon Muttersprachler bist, dann könntest Du auch auf Deutsch gefragt haben...

Comment: OT: Floskelhafte Einstiegssätze sind bei Bewerbungen zu vermeiden.... http://bewerbung.net/top-floskeln-in-bewerbungen/

Comment: @Iris Das stimmt. Ich vermisse auf der verlinkten Seite aber positive Gegenbeispiele.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar, das stimmt leider. Bei der letzten Karrieremesse, auf der ich war, hieß es, man solle sich an der Ausschreibung orientieren (z.B. Ingenieurstelle ausgeschrieben, Berufserfahrung vorausgesetzt), z.B. "Sehr geehrte Frau xyz, ich bin Diplom-Ingenieur und arbeite seit 5 Jahren bei Firma ... im Bereich ....  "

Comment: I want to mention that it is better to say "Ihr Unternehmen" here instead of "Ihre Firma". Unternehmen sounds more professional. As for HGB, Firma means actually the name of the company, not the company itself, though this is not the common meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. You're referring to the company of the person you're adressing (it doesn't necessarily be that the company is owned by that person) using the polite "Sie". To say "your xyz" in the German polite form, you use "Ihr/Ihren/Ihre", depending on the Genus of the noun. So it would be

> ... Ihr Auto (because it is **das** Auto)
>   ... Ihren Wagen (because it is **der** Wagen)
>   ... Ihre Firma (because it is **die** Firma)

So is it correct, but it's the only correct form.

Better formatting and word order would be:

> Sehr geehrte Frau xyz,
>    durch das Stellenangebot [wo] bin ich auf Ihre Firma aufmerksam geworden.

Also replace `[wo]` with the place where you found the job advertisement.

To be totally safe, you could also change this to:

> Sehr geehrte Frau xyz,
>    durch das Stellenangebot [wo] bin ich auf [Firmenname] aufmerksam geworden.

Comment: In the last sentence I would leave out `die Firma`. I would just write `[...]bin ich auf [Firmenname] aufmerksam geworden.`

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is. I have successfully applied for jobs using this term.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more, maybe from a language standpoint? I could also say "it's ok to cross the street at a red light because I've successfully done so a few times". As is, your answer is likely to get deleted.

Comment: I'm very unsure with this language structure and I'm native german speaker, which is the reason I asked the question here. It should be ok from a grammatical view point but since the secretary does not owns the company "ihre" is wrong form the content view point.

Comment: @Robert: Die Antwort beantwortet die gestellte Frage.

Comment: @Fritz: Ich besitze auch nicht meine Famliie, meinen Fußballclub, mein Lieblingseis, meine Heimat usw.

Comment: @Fritz Ich bin Mitglied meiner Familie - besitze ich deshalb meine Familie?